# Speeding up grep in a for loop for big file sizes (30GB)

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a below code to transform/map a set of text files based on multiple look up files. After my if condition logic, I place them on multiple files and concatenate them at the end.
To speed this up, I tried to run this in multiple processes, and use LC_all=C fgrep but is still taking up a day to complete. my first for loop of skus have around 20k iterations, and this is grepping the skus on a 30GB file and placing the output on the 5 different files.
Is there a more efficient way to go about this?
Note: Just to add, there is no way for me to install GNU parallel function on the server.

```
PROCESSES=8
for sku in `cat ${outFile}_skusOnly`; do
expr_max_processes=$(jobs -l | wc -l)

while [[ $expr_max_processes -ge $PROCESSES ]];do
  sleep 5
  expr_max_processes=$(jobs -l | wc -l)
  done
{
column_number=`awk -F"," -v b="$sku" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i == b) { print i } }}' ${dir}/Univ_CF_Map.csv | head -1`
   if [[ $column_number -eq 1 ]];
  then
  SS_TYPE=`LC_ALL=C fgrep $sku ${dir}/Univ_SS_FCST_Lvl.csv | awk -F"," '{print $NF}'`
     if [[ $SS_TYPE == "U" ]];
     then
        LC_ALL=C fgrep -h $sku ${outFile} >> ${outFile}_sorted_sku_mapped_UUU_$sku
     elif [[ $SS_TYPE == "C" ]];
     then
        Forecast_SKU=`LC_ALL=C fgrep $sku ${dir}/Univ_CF_Map.csv | grep F | awk -F"," '{print $2}'`
        LC_ALL=C fgrep -h $sku ${outFile}| sed "s/$sku/$Forecast_SKU/g" >> ${outFile}_sorted_sku_mapped_CUF_$sku
     fi
  elif [[ $column_number -eq 2 ]];
  then
     Parent_SKU=`LC_ALL=C fgrep $sku ${dir}/Univ_CF_Map.csv | awk -F"," '{print $1}' | head -1`
     SS_TYPE=`LC_ALL=C fgrep $Parent_SKU ${dir}/Univ_SS_FCST_Lvl.csv | awk -F"," '{print $NF}'`
        if [[ $SS_TYPE == "U" ]];
        then
        LC_ALL=C fgrep -h $sku ${outFile} | sed "s/$sku/$Parent_SKU/g" >> ${outFile}_sorted_sku_mapped_UCU_$sku
        elif [[ $SS_TYPE == "C" ]];
        then
        LC_ALL=C fgrep -h $sku ${outFile} >> ${outFile}_sorted_sku_mapped_CCC_$sku
        fi
  else
  LC_ALL=C fgrep -h $sku ${outFile} >> ${outFile}_sorted_sku_mapped_as_is_$sku
  fi
  }   &
done
wait
```

Comment: I'm really unclear about the numbers here. If I understand correctly you've got about 20k SKUs (I assume those are just some IDs) that you are searching for in *one* 30GB file (i.e. you search through that file 20k times for one ID each?) to extract *some other data* related to that SKU and write that to a new file. is that correct?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to do everything as an awk script ? The `grep` + `if` + `awk` can all be done in one `awk` command. Same thing with the `sed`.

Comment: I don't understand the flow either, but my first thought is: can you do a one-pass search through the big file for *all* of the SKUs (or at least a big batch of them at a time), then do per-SKU searches on the result of that thinned-to-just-the-interesting-entries file?

Comment: I don't think grep is a good tool for such a situation

Comment: @JoachimSauer  Yes. but I have extracted the 20k skus beforehand from that big chunk of 30GB file with sort -u. Basically that 30GB file contains those 20k skus but with different values.(about 300 million records).

In my loop, i determine the structure of an ID/SKU. after i determine the output, I grep all this ID/SKU on that big file and change all their structure. (i.e all ids=1 i  use sed to update to parent id=A)

I could just not extract all the skus in that big file by doing an awk but i think that would just do more loops. I'm also not that great in complicated awks so I used if.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the flow, but I'm pretty sure that the fact that have 20k passes through the 30GB file will cause the performance and reducing that number (ideally to 1) will be the single-greatest improvement in performance that you'll get here. This *may* be doable using just `awk` (I don't have enough experience with it to know for sure), but maybe a dedicated program that does that for you in the language of your choice (Python, Perl, C, Java, ... doesn't really matter much, it should be reasonably simple in any one) will be so much faster.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way, otherwise all we can say so far is - don't do that!

Answer (score 1):

Scanning a 30GB file 20k times is sub-optimal, because you perform the inefficient operation (30GB of I/O) in an inner loop 20k times.  Parallel processes are unlikely to help you here, because most likely your job is I/O-bound rather than CPU-bound.  (You should verify this using *top* and *iostat*.)

Focus on scanning the large file just once.  For example, consider passing the list of all SKUs to *fgrep* using its `-f` option. The *fgrep* program is designed to perform this operation very efficiently.  If this isn't possible, rewrite the code in a scripting language, such as *Python*.